# Make localhost/... popup localhost:3000/

Tags: javascript, popup, localhost, postmessage

I have a local file `a.html` as follows, which can be launched by `https://localhost/a.html`. by clicking on `Open b`, it can open another file `b.html`, then by `Send` button, it could send data by `postMessage`:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <p onclick="openWindow()">Open b</p>
    <form>
      <input type="button" value="Send">
    </form>

    <script>
      function openWindow() {
        var popup = window.open("https://localhost/b.html", "popup", "width=200, height=200");
        // var popup = window.open("https://localhost:3000/#/new", "popup", "width=1000, height=1000");

        var button = document.querySelector("form input[type=button]");
        button.onclick = function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          e.stopPropagation();      
          popup.postMessage("hi, how are you?", popup.location.href);
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now, rather than opening `https://localhost/b.html`, I want to open a page `https://localhost:3000/#/new` served by a local application. So I uncomment the line `var popup = window.open("https://localhost:3000/#/new", "popup", "width=1000, height=1000");`. Then it raises an error while opening it:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://localhost" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
    at HTMLInputElement.button.onclick (https://localhost/a.html:20:49)
```

So it seems that `https://localhost/` and `https://localhost:3000/` are considered as **cross-origin**.

Does anyone have any solution or workaround to make `https://localhost/a.html` open `https://localhost:3000/#/new`?

**Edit 1:** I use Mac. Actually when going to production, everything will be put under a same domain `www.myexample.com`, which has static files like `a.html` and runs a server. I just want to have an easy solution for development in `localhost` in Mac.

**Edit 2:** A limitation is that, I have to open `a.html` by `https://localhost/a.html`; I am NOT allowed to use `http` or serve it as a static file (ie, `https://localhost:3000/a.html`).

Comment: They are simply cross origin, and you would need a reverse proxy like nginx to make them same server.

Comment: I use mac, I just want to have an easy solution for development in `localhost`, please see my PS...

Comment: What are you using to serve the files? https on localhost is nothing more than stupid, since most browser treats localhost specially and adding a self signed certificate for that doesn't make sense.

Comment: Did you try editing the host file to point it where you want?

Comment: @iDev I have control of all the files

Comment: @TatsuyukiIshi I don't understand well your question. I prefer to open `a.html` and `localhost:3000/#/new` with `https`, but if you have solution in case of `http`, that will be great too.

Comment: You need a server, either the one integrated in your framework, or a static specific one to serve the files. What are you using?

Comment: I do have a local MEAN stack server, that's why `localhost/#/new` works when the server is on. `a.html` is independent of the server. In production, I have several websites hosted by Windows Server or nginx. But at the moment, I want to be able to develop and have a solution in local.

Comment: Yeah, not totally understanding. Can you browse to this https://localhost:3000/#/new in the web browser on the local machine? Are you currently using OS X Server?

Comment: @iDv i can browser to localhost:3000#/new in a web browser when my server is on (`npm start`). I am using mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is open Chrome in a terminal with some special arguments:

```
open -a Google\ Chrome --args --disable-web-security --user-data-dir=/Users/SoftTimur/Desktop/user-data-dir
```

I have also tried some Chrome add-ins, which did NOT work for my tests.

It will be great if we have a solution (eg, some setting) without having to open Chrome from a terminal each time...

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned you're using MEAN stack, so I assume you are using ExpressJS.

It's possible to serve static (for development): see http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Do NOT use https on localhost... It makes nothing more secure and just add an unneeded self-signed certificate.

For a more generic solution, nginx can be used to serve static files and pass other paths to the backend.

Comment: For some reason, I have to open `a.html` by `https://localhost/a.html`; I cannot use `http` for that or serve it as static file. Please see my update.

Comment: @SoftTimur elaborate **why** you can't do that. You're probably doing local development wrong.

Comment: actually, 'a.html' is the main page of a microsft office addin I am developing (by javascript api for office). Their rule is to refer to the main page with 'https' rather than 'http'. We cannot refer to the main page with a port ':3000' either.

Comment: I'd recommend to improve the add-in (the root of evil); however, if you can't, just use nginx locally. It supports any SSL certificates as well as forwarding to multiple backends.

Comment: is it possible to use nginx in macOS?

Comment: Who told you no? nginx is surely cross platform.